# Angular2 - Login with gapi

Tags: angular, google-api

I would like to add google authentication button.

In the index.html file I have this meta:

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

and in the root compoponent I have this one:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('rvep ngOnInit');
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    console.log('gapi.load');
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    });

    if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
      auth2.signIn();
    }

    console.log('is user signed in: ' + auth2.isSignedIn.get());
  });
}
```

and in the login.component:

```
// Angular hook that allows for interaction with elements inserted by the
// rendering of a view.
ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Converts the Google login button stub to an actual button.
  gapi.signin2.render("rvepGoogleSignin",
  {
     "onSuccess": this.onSuccess,
     "scope": "profile",
     "theme": "dark"
   });
}
```

But the button doesn't apper. What I do wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this is your .html file?

```
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
  <div id="my-signin2" (data-onsuccess)="onSignIn"></div>
  <span>&#8203;</span>
</div>
```